# Amazon EC2 time zone

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 dedicated instance (Fedora Linux). Although I took an instance in US West, it came set to EST.
 I changed the timezone to PST (`export TZ=America/Los_Angeles`) and it works - for several hours. Then it resets itself to EST.

What am I doing wrong and how can I set it to PST permanently?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't run Fedora for my EC2 instances as I need something stable for more than 6 months, so I use CentOS... But it should be the same... Just run the following:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
```

That should change your systems default timezone to PST and should only be affected when the instance is brought up from scratch.

Comment: Thanks! Also for the CentOs note. You're the second one to tell me the same this week.

Comment: With Fedora's release every 6 months and only support the most current 3 versions policy you're unsupported after 18 months.

Comment: +1, worked like a charm. For those non-sysadmins like me, prefix with `sudo`

Answer (score 2):

Change the `ZONE` setting in `/etc/sysconfig/clock`

Comment: No such file in /etc/sysconfig :(

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy the file is there for Amazon Linux AMI (Centos). I'm not sure if it's there for other types of AMI

Answer (score 0):

Have the config for setting timezone in your .bashrc .

In case you are looking for using the TZ in your application from the system, its a bad idea since EC2 instances that go down/crash can be a different system when they come back up.