# Prevent Amazon EC2 Time zone from reverting back on yum update

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2, redhat, amazon-ami

I use an Amazon EC2 server instance that runs a distro called [Amazon Linux AMI](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/). (I've read that it is based on CentOS/Red Hat). My specific version is the [2012.09 release](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2012.09-release-notes/).

Anyway, I was able to change the time zone about a week ago from the default UTC to America/New_York (which is EST/EDT). The command I used to change it was:

```
    ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
```

...thanks to [this other Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/110142/amazon-ec2-time-zone). At that point, I was able to run `date` from the the command line, and it correctly displayed the EDT time. And even after EDT "fell back" to EST this past Sunday, I was pleased to find that running `date` still produced the correct local time. So that was great.

However, after running a `yum update` yesterday, it seems that my time zone got reverted back to plain 'ol UTC. I even checked the last modified time of `/etc/localtime` file, and indeed it confirmed that it had been modified around the same time I had updated.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening again, or will I be stuck resetting the time zone every time I do a `yum update`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure the time zone is also changed in

```
/etc/sysconfig/clock
```

by setting

```
ZONE="America/New_York"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I plan to accept your post if, after implementing your changes and running a `yum update` (when updates are available of course) my time zone does not revert. In the meantime, I checked `/etc/sysconfig/clock` and it has `ZONE="UTC"` and `UTC=true`. Do i need to make it say `UTC=false`? or do I only change ZONE?

Comment: Changing only the ZONE will suffice

Comment: I am having the same issue. I changed the timezone in `/etc/timezone` but it reverts back to UTC every time I log out of the server. And for whatever reason `/etc/sysconfig` doesn't exist for me, so I can't modify the `clock` file. Any hints?

Comment: What will for IST, I wrote ZONE="Indian", but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I run on mine to keep them in Pacific Time:

```
sed -i '/ZONE/c \ZONE="America\/Los_Angeles"' /etc/sysconfig/clock
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
```

Comment: Thanks for the script Jason. kernelpanic mentioned that `UTC=false` is not necessary. If, after my testing, I find that it is necessary, I may very well mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Let me know if it turns out you don't need it, I might be setting it false unnecessarily.

Comment: EC2 hardware clocks are in UTC so the UTC=false line shouldn't be added.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jason. I'm not sure if changing UTC to `false` will prevent the correct local time from displaying or not, but regardless, just leaving it at the default value of `UTC=true` seemed to be fine for me. If you want to "experiment" with various settings, I was able to test updates using `yum history undo [a number]` command. I would test `date` before and after the undo to see if it retained EST